# how vuforia assign position/cordinates to object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, object-tracking

I am using unity to track the position of two different objects and calculate distance between them. I have fixed my object A as my Word Center which mean that object A position is fixed. Now when camera detect object A vuforia assign position to the camera with refrence to object A. If i move camera object A position remain same but camera position changes which is fine. Now i introduce object B to the camera view and when it detect object B it assign position to Object B. The position of object B is reference to what ? camera or object A. ? If i move camera the position of object B changes which should not change if i have my word Center fixed to object A.

How Vuforia assign position to object B.? or how to calculate distance between these two objects.?

Comment: vuforia works in environments that themselves already provide a world reference (e.g. HoloLens, Oculus Quest etc) so usually your Camera is already controlled by the according framework and moves through your Unity scene. Then you track an image and Vuforia sets it to according position in your scene which already is overlayed to your real world -> what exactly are you trying to achieve / what exactly doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
What i want to achieve is to calculate distance between two objects.
What does not behave as when i move camera around the distance between two object changes which should not change by moving camera only.

Comment: what Camera exactly? What XR framework are you using?

Comment: Development environment is unity and i am using I pad  Camera. I have deployed app to both IOS and android phone for testing.